# vim colorscheme is overriding tmux code for changing active/inactive pane color

Tags: tmux, nvim

I have this code in .tmux.conf:

```
set -g window-style 'fg=colour247,bg=colour234'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour250,bg=black'
```

It works and "dims" an inactive pane by making it appear slightly greyer.

It also works when vim is running in a pane, but only when there is no colorscheme. As soon as I use a colorscheme with `colorscheme koehler`, the dimming effect stops working. Tried this in my vim config to see if I could get the panes to go grey:

```
hi ActiveWindow ctermbg=gray ctermfg=gray         
hi InactiveWindow ctermbg=gray ctermfg=gray 
set winhighlight=Normal:ActiveWindow,NormalNC:InactiveWindow
```

But it did not do anything. I'm using a tty, not a gui.

Comment: From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48330643/1641112

Answer (score 0):

OK, adding this to init.lua appears to do the trick:

`vim.cmd [[ highlight Normal guibg=NONE ]]`

Make sure the line comes after the colorscheme is set.

I have no idea why setting `guibg` in a terminal version of neovim works.